# How to link menu <li> to nav bars links

Tags: html, angularjs

I have navigation links:-

```
<!-- Navigation tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tab-menu">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tab2">Tab2</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Also I have side menu bar which consists of the same tabs:-

```
<ul class="sub-menu collapse" data-target="">
   <li data-toggle="modal" id="Tab1">
      <a>Tab1</a>
   </li>
   <li data-toggle="modal" id="Tab1">
      <a>Tab2</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want to link nav tabs to menu tabs. How to do that? Also this nav tabs have different Html's and directives link to them.

Comment: "I want to link nav tabs to menu tabs." What do you mean by this?

Comment: FYI - You have 2 `<li>`'s with same ID.

Comment: post your css in your question

Comment: <ul class="sub-menu collapse" data-target="">
   <li data-toggle="modal" id="Tab1">
      <a>Tab1</a></li>
   <li data-toggle="modal" id="Tab2">
      <a>Tab2</a></li>
</ul>. Also by linking nav tabs to menu tabs I mean when I click on menu <li>Tab1 or Tab2 it is link(switch) to nav tabs Tab1&Tab2